# is it possible to use np.isclose with tolerance and merging original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to use numpy.isclose with tolerence to check values of column but also need add original value compared with it.

edit:
ok i want to search the dataframe for some value but with some tolerance
say for 100+-1  check >99 and <101 .
if some data found then merge that with original check value which is 100.
I come with np.isclose but it only filters values what i want but the merging part is missing. check below demo data

some demo dataframes:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[str('2020-02-11'),'AAA',100],
                [str('2020-02-12'),'AAA',105]],columns=['Date','Name','Amount'])

df2=pd.DataFrame(range(97,105),columns=['data'])

df3=df2[np.isclose(df2.data.values[:, None],[df.Amount.to_list()],atol=1).any(axis=1)]
```

This is my dataframe df and df2

```
        Date    Name  Amount
0   2020-02-11  AAA    100
1   2020-02-12  AAA    105

   data
0   97
1   98
2   99
3   100
4   101
5   102
6   103
7   104
```

this is what filtered dataframe df3 looks like
here tolarance is 1
so it checks for [99,**100**,101] and [104,**105**,106]

```
   data
2   99
3   100
4   101
7   104
```

but want this. here *100* is used to filter[99,100,101] and *105* is used for 104

```
   data  Amount    Date
2   99    100     2020-02-11
3   100   100     2020-02-11
4   101   100     2020-02-11
7   104   105     2020-02-12
```

Comment: Is it one-to-one or can one entry in df2 match multiple in df?

Comment: i want to match df2['data'] with df1 values of "Amount" columns on within tolerence

Comment: that part is clear. The question is is it possible that one df2 values matches multiple entries of df?

Comment: even if i passed single value how to know which original value used for filtering

Comment: you need to specify it so we can post a relevant answer.

Comment: i want to know which original value of df is used to filter df2. in given demo 100 is used

Comment: Haha, you keep repeating the question without answering the comment. Anyways I will post an answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the matching ones by subtracting:

```
r2,r=np.where(np.abs(df.Amount.values-df2.data.values[:,None])<=1)
pd.concat([df.iloc[r].reset_index(),df2.iloc[r2].reset_index()],1)
```

of course you can easily select the columns you want in the output and remove irrelevant columns you do not want (I did not include in the answer)

output:

```
   index        Date Name  Amount  index  data
0      0  2020-02-11  AAA     100      2    99
1      0  2020-02-11  AAA     100      3   100
2      0  2020-02-11  AAA     100      4   101
3      1  2020-02-12  AAA     105      7   104
```